# How to find packages that are not listed in aptitude

Tags: aptitude

Often there are some packages that I was required to install as prerequisites of some tools, but are not listed in the aptitude package list (or with a slightly different name).

For example, I once encounter an error saying "libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.", and by searching the error I resolved it by run "sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6". So the required package is lib32stdc++6, how could I tell it from the name libstdc++.so.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called `apt-file` that allows you to search for files in packages. You first need to initialize it by running `sudo apt-file update`, and then you can run `apt-file search libstdc++.so.6`. This will at least point you in the right direction.

You can also use Synaptic (or similar) to search for a package that contains the library name.

Comment: This tools provides some information for finding packages, although   some knowledges about the packages you are going to install is inevitable.

Comment: Absolutely. On another note, if you know the exact path you are expecting a file to be at (which has been almost never in my case), you can use the `-F` parameter. For example, `apt-file search -F /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6`.